# Regex for finding a string recursively?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I have a set of commands listed in a file say commands.txt and I was trying to find all the php scripts recursively inside a directory using grep -r but I am not successful in substituting the variable that I get from the commands.txt into the grep.

For example,

when I try

```
grep -R --include "*.php" <command> .
```

I get the desired result but when I try to do a for loop like

```
for i in `cat /var/tmp/commands.txt`; do 'grep -R --include *.php $i .' ; done
```

or

```
for i in `cat /var/tmp/commands`; do 'echo $i | grep -r --include *.php .' ; done
```

the expression fails.

Comment: sorry if that confused you,its the input from the command.txt

Comment: like what $i would return when in the for statement.

Comment: So you are storing search terms inside `command.txt`? Can you show a sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find commands from `/var/tmp/commands.txt` in the PHP files in the current directory and its subdirectories, with (what looks like) GNU `grep`?  You might go about it like this:

```
fgrep -Rwf /var/tmp/commands.txt --include '*.php' .
```